# Remove resource files from APK

Tags: gradle, android-studio, wear-os

I have an Mobie/Android Wear project which share a library for resources.
How can I exclude some big bitmaps from being shared in Wear apk?

Comment: Try to use [shrinkResources](https://plus.google.com/+TorNorbye/posts/eHsStybrrBf)

Answer (score 0):

You should have 2 libraries:
one common for Mobie/Wear, the other only for Mobile. 
Then move big files into Mobile lib

Answer (score 0):

If you don't select particular file from drawables (or any other) and send it using DataItem API they won't be synchronized, so there is nothing to worry about. Second option is to include them before compiling to 'wear' module in 'res/drawable' but if you don't do it, it won't happen automatically.